# Does collections of function on $\mathbb{R}_+$ means domain or range?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, terminology

I do not fully understand a hint from Erhan Cinlar's Probability and Stochastics (its on page 67). This is the hint:

> Let $F$ be the collection of all function $f$ on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}_+$ having the form $f(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}c_ie^{-r_ix}$ for some integer $n\geq 1$, constants $c_1,...,c_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and constants $r_1,...,r_n$ in $\mathbb{R}_+$.

My question is, is $\bar{\mathbb{R}}_+$ the domain, or the range of the functions $f$ (in collection $F$)?

Comment: The preposition "on" signifies that it is domain. You can view it as a shorthand for "defined on".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in one word, it's 'related' to domain.

$c_1,\ldots,c_n$ belong to domain $\mathbb{R}$, and $r_1,\ldots,r_n$ belong to domain $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ (Non-negative R).

Hence, '$\mathbb{R}^{+}$' is not the domain, but the set point out by $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ is part of the domain  and not range. I hope this helps!

Comment: Please type up your answer using MathJax (you won't need more than the sub/super scripts _ ^ and \mathbb{R})

Comment: Thanks, new to this platform but will surely learn faster

Answer (score 1):

"On" means the domain of the function. That is, "functions on $\Omega$" means functions with domain $\Omega$. Sometimes we might say "functions on $\Omega$ valued in $\Omega'$", which means that the functions are $f:\Omega\to \Omega'$.